# ASP.NET - icon inside <input>

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net-core, razor

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info w-100" value="Create" />
```

And I have this icon.

```
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
```

But there is no place for it inside `input`. What is the best way to bypass this issue?

Comment: You can use a button tag instead of an input with the Value attribute being replaced by the inner content of the tag.

Comment: @Brandon I'm not familiar with non-input performing POST. I'm trying to figure this out right now, but I wouldn't mind getting sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a button tag instead of an input with the Value attribute being replaced by the inner content of the tag.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info w-100">
  <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
  Create
</button>
```

Comment: Yeah just figured out button has type="submit". Marking as solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `button` and need for whatever reason an `input` you could wrap it around a container to add the icon as a `pseudoelement` with your icon over your button  (I have used font awesome but you can use an image as `background-image` ). but don't forget to use `pointer-events:none;` so you can click on the input behind.

```
<div>
  <input type="submit">
</div>

div {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
input { 
padding-right:30px;

}
div:after {
   content: "\f007";
   font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
   display:block;
   top:5px;
   right:10px;
   position:absolute;
   pointer-events:none;
}
```

Like this: **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bhpmt9k3/1/)**